# Starting/Stopping Marionette Modules and Routing

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How can we handle starting/stopping modules between routes without explicitly telling the route's controller method to start/stop each module.

```
var AppRouterController = {
  index: function() {
    // Start only modules I need for this route here
    // in this case, HomeApp only
    App.module('HomeApp').start();
    // Stop all modules that should not be running for this route
    // The idea, being that not everyone has to come to the index route first
    // They could have been to many other routes with many different modules starting at each route before here
    App.module('Module1').stop();
    App.module('ModuleInfinity').stop();
    // ...
    // ...
    // This could get tedious, expensive, and there has to be a better way.
  },
  someOtherRouteMethod: function() {
    // Do it all over again
  }
}
```

I know I am doing something wrong here, hopefully not fundamentally, but please let me know if there is a better way. Module management is going to be key for this project due to that fact that it will be running primarily on tablet devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like overkill that you are starting and stopping every module in each route. There isn't much built into Marionette to help you with juggling your modules like that.

What I would recommend if you really want to do that is to write a wrapper for your routes that takes a list of modules to start and I function to run after starting/stopping modules.

Something like this:

```
(function (App) {
  var listOfAllModules = ["HomeApp", "Module1", ...];
  window.moduleWrapper = function (neededModules, route) {
    return function () {
      _.each(_.without(listOfAllModules, neededModules), function (moduleName) {
        App.module(moduleName).stop();
      });
      _.each(neededModules, function (moduleName) {
        App.module(moduleName).start();
      });
      route.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
})(App);
```

Then, in your routers just wrap routes that need to juggle modules.

```
var AppRouterController = {
  index: moduleWrapper(["HomeApp"], function() {
    // Only routing logic left...
  })
};
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Perhaps, I am thinking of how to handle my modules incorrectly. I was under the impression something like this only made sense. After all, why would a want a module, perhaps, 3 clicks away running from the HomeApp. I will certainly use this approach if it's the best way to go. Is there are a good reason to not consider starting modules only as they are actually needed?

Comment: In my experience, starting modules selectively is useful for a couple different things. 1. You have separate scripts that are not part of your main app but that you will need on some pages. A good example is something like a graphing library that uses d3.js where you only need that code and your surrounding module on specific parts of the app. 2. Your module is responsible for a large portion of start up code that isn't otherwise relevant. For example, something like a live demonstration page that generates a bunch of fake data on start.